# How to use jQuery UI's datepicker in Apps Script's HTML Service?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, google-apps-script

I've managed to display the calendar in the UI, but I can't make it react to any events. I've tried

```
$(function() {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
           onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {alert(dateText); }
       });
    });
```

but it doesn't work... Please help

Comment: You may look on the page source to check if the script is rendering the same javascript code as you have written in your html page. HtmlService uses Google-Caja to filter unsafe javascript, html and CSS code. Please confirm if your function(dateText, inst) {alert(dateText); is not being filtered.

Comment: You may test your code in Caja-playground http://caja.appspot.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me. Issue filed with Caja as [issue 1496](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/detail?id=1496).

Update: turns out this is a jQueryUI bug, which is fixed in the latest jQuery revision but not the official stable revision (8.22). If you find a link to a version >= 8.22 hosted somewhere it should work although it will be slowish. We will get the update as soon as jQueryUI releases a new stable branch.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your input. Is there any feed I can subscribe to that would notify me when the 1.8.22 version is available?

Comment: I don't know, but it appears that you can use this link for the time being to patch up jQuery: http://www.thinkfu.com/jquery.ui.datepicker.js